# MYSQL / PHP / YII2: Occupied VS. Vacant Rooms - Dashboard

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

OK I understand that it is a general question. But I have virtually looked everywhere and couldn't find a direction from where to start.

I want to create a grahphical layout/Dashboard, which will show occupied/vacant rooms as in the attached picture.

for specifics I have a mysql tables like room_category, room_name and patient_detail(admission) with field like

**room_category**

```
id   room_category
```

**room_name**

```
id room_name  room_category(id)
```

**Patient_admission**

```
id patient_name(id) room_category(id) room_name(id)
admission_date_time is_discharged discharge_date_time
```

I have presented here only the necessary fields for brevity.

I am able to query the database individually for occupied rooms or for vacant rooms.
But I am bit lost how can create a dashboard like report which will show in a single report both occupied and vacant rooms like below that is green for **Occupied** and red for **Vacant**
[image]

Comment: I might misunderstand you, but why cant you do a relational query with Patient_admission and make the background red if is_discharged = false, and green if its true?